# Changing a python code to splash the images

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python sample codes whihc is from mask-rccn python repository. The codes purposes are to splash a sample image based on an existing mask

```
gray = skimage.color.gray2rgb(skimage.color.rgb2gray(image)) * 255
# Copy color pixels from the original color image where mask is set
if mask.shape[-1] > 0:
    # We're treating all instances as one, so collapse the mask into one layer
    ***image[mask]=255***
    mask = (np.sum(mask, -1, keepdims=True) >= 1)
    splash = np.where(mask, image, gray).astype(np.uint8)
else:
    splash = gray.astype(np.uint8)
return splash
```

The codes above change the mask parts inact while I want to make them white or blue. I have added a line to make the mask parts white,
`image[mask]=255`

Bu this gave me error when I run the codes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 334, in <module>
    video_path=args.video)
  File "test.py", line 206, in detect_and_color_splash
    splash = color_splash(image, r['masks'])
  File "test.py", line 186, in color_splash
    image[mask]=255
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 2; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 19
```

Comment: instead of `gray`, you want to fill in `white`? I guess you have to derive "white" the same way you derive "gray".

Comment: Actually no, the background is gray images but I need to make changes to foreground mask image.